# Python: How do you catch UNIX signals received in subprocess?

Tags: python, linux, signals

I want my Python program to run a non-Python program, be notified of the Unix signals that the subprocess receives, and handle them.
In this specific case I want to handle `SIGXFSZ` for my child process.

Is this possible?

Comment: I'm pretty sure Unix doesn't allow receiving or catching a child's signals. You'd have to catch it in the child and send it to the parent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, parent or other processes cannot catch/intercept/receive signals generated for another process.

However, if the SIGXFSZ terminates your child process, the parent can know this. 
 If using python's `subprocess` module, a ["negative [returncode] value -N indicates that the child was terminated by signal N (POSIX only)."](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CompletedProcess.returncode)

For example, on my system  SIGXFSZ is signal no. 25, and thus death by XFSZ is a return code of -25:

```
$ python -c 'import signal; print(repr(signal.SIGXFSZ))'
<Signals.SIGXFSZ: 25>

$ python -c 'import subprocess; print(subprocess.call(["kill -XFSZ $$"], shell=True))'
-25
```

If not using the `subprocess` module, the fatal signal information is still encoded in the status returned to [`os.waitpid()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.waitpid) via the helper functions `WIFSIGNALED` and `WTERMSIG`.